# Rendering raster layer from DTED based on height color map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, dted

I have a raster layer that was create from DTED file (dt1 specifically), created by the following code:

```
var rasterLayer = new RasterLayer();
rasterLayer.CreateFromFilePath(dtedFilePath);
```

The dted file is treated like raster and is displayed as grayscale.

From the other hand, I have a color map file (.clr) that maps specific colors to specific elevation values.
The file is in the form

```
0 63 187 239
1 63 187 239
2 125 198 34
...
2806 220 220 220
```

I would like, somehow, to have that coloring (the one in the clr file) used by some kind o renderer to render the aforementioned raster layer.

Is there any way to do this?

We are talking about a windows form application written in C#, with a simple map control in the center. I'm using ArcGIS Engine 10